# Keep Discord Bot online on repl.it

Tags: python, discord, keep-alive

How do I use `repl.it` for my Python Discord Bot, and keep it running 24/7. 
I used to use `keep_alive` but it stops working for some reason.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I keep getting this error in the console:

> 172.18.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2019 11:25:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: This isn't an error message, [on the contrary](https://httpstatuses.com/200), it indicates success

Comment: Does repl.it actually allow you to run a program with unbounded runtime? They're not really a hosting service.

Answer (score 21):

**To keep your repl.it bot online 24/7 you have to do 3 things :**

1. keeping the bot alive
2. adding a background task
3. link your repl.it bot with uptime robot

**1. To keep our bot alive we have to add the following code on the head of our py file:**

```py
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def main():
  return "Your Bot Is Ready"

def run():
  app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

def keep_alive():
  server = Thread(target=run)
  server.start()
```

**2. Adding a background task :**

```py
status = cycle(['with Python','JetHub'])

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  change_status.start()
  print("Your bot is ready")

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def change_status():
  await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))
```

**3. Setup the [Uptime Robot](https://uptimerobot.com) :**

- Create an account on uptime robot.
- After creating an account, go to the dashboard and click on Add new monitor [image: (preview)]
- select monitor type Http(s) [image: (preview)]
- then go to to ur project on repl.it and copy the url from the top of the console and paste it in url section of the monitor [image: (preview)]
- now set the monitoring interval to every 5 mins (so that it will ping the bot every 5 mins) and click on create monitor twice [image: (preview)]
- That’s it… Now go to ur project on repl.it and hit the Run button

If you have made your discord bot in **discord.js**, I wrote a medium article on that : [Host a Discord Bot 24/7 Online for FREE!](https://medium.com/jethub/host-a-discord-bot-24-7-online-for-free-4f30cd8ba78e)

Comment: the functions keep_alive and run are not called so what do you need to do to make the server online

Comment: In case anyone like me doesn't know, tasks can be imported with this :
from discord.ext import tasks
Also I had to replace "bot" by "client" because it seems to have that name in my internet-inspired code.

Answer (score 1):

Although @Skidee's solution seems to work, there is a major issue. Repl.it uses shared IPs. And doing that will cause discord's cloudflare to throw a 429 too many requests. Thus, even though you are keeping the repl running using uptimerobot or buying the paid always-up repls, you will not be able to keep your bot online all the time.

Using a VPS is the ***ONLY*** solution to the problem. Plus, no good hosting is free. Use Amazon cloud if you are in the U.S. because it provides a 12-month trial.

> 172.18.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2019 11:25:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

This "error" message doesn't mean anything errored. On the contrary, it indicates your `keep_alive` functoin has started working.

Refer to [Discord API cloudflare banning my repl.it repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75171845/discord-api-cloudflare-banning-my-repl-it-repo) if you want to know more.