# Need help discord bot command

Tags: python, discord.py

I just started learning python recently and never coded a discord bot before. I've been trying to get the bot to connect to the voice or respond to **">hello"**, but it doesn't respond to my command and I don't know how to fix it. I'm using [replit](http://replit.com) as hosting.

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '>', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Log in as {0.user}'.format(client))
  print('-------------------')

@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello Im Deemo Bot")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
  if (ctx.author.voice):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
  else:
    await ctx.send('You are not in a voice channel')

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def leave(ctx):
  if (ctx.voice_client):
    await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
    await ctx.send('Deemo left voice')
  else:
    await ctx.send('Deemo is not in voice')

keep_alive()
client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

Comment: Try `ctx.channel.send` instead of just `ctx.send`

Comment: Most likely your `keep_alive()` is blocking the code from running. Most repl.it keep alive implementation relies on flask which is synchronous and has an internal loop that blocks your Discord bot. You'll need to share that function for us to help you.

Comment: @DragonInTraining `ctx.send` is a shortcut for `ctx.channel.send`, they're equivalent.

Comment: @Taku Today I learn, I actually had some problems a few weeks ago with my bot, with sending messages to the channel before I added `.channel` to `ctx.send`. But you're probably right, as far as I know, keep_alive() isn't needed in replit.com.

Comment: @DragonInTraining Hi, I just doubled checked, internally discord.py `ctx.send` redirects to `ctx.channel.send` (line 215 of context.py), and it's been like this ever since v1.2 I believe (a year or two ago). So changing that wouldn't do anything, not sure what caused your problem but it shouldn't be related. And I meant `keep_alive()` is needed for repl.it (otherwise repl.it will shutoff the app) but the OP needs a good implementation so that it doesn't block the code.

Comment: keep_alive() I use with uptimerobot to keep the bot onl 24/7
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return('Hello, I am Deemo Bot ~~ ')

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)
def keep_alive():
  t = Thread(target=run)
  t.start()

Comment: @Aina what about other commands? Only `hello` command doesn't work or others too?

Comment: In that case, everything seems okay not sure what's your issue, you can follow the post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54722596/keep-discord-bot-online-on-repl-it and see which step you missed. (ie. is your bot file named main.py)

Comment: i managed the bot to respond to all commands accept >join, it doesnt join voice channel.
i gave the bot permission. If i'm not in a voice channel the bot still rep "You are not in a voice channel" but when i'm connet to voice i doesnt do anything

Comment: And do you get any errors? And you can also try going to `shell` (next to console) and writing `python -m pip install PyNaCl` - it's a library required for joining and playing audio by Discord BOT. You can also make sure that you installed the audio support version of discord.py by running `python -m pip install discord.py[voice]`.